# Mac: How to get the status of a status icon on the menu bar of screen?

Tags: icons, status, detect, menubar, mode

For a Chinese or Japanese user, we all need to input text other than English. Therefore we have an icon on the menu bar to show what is the current input mode. There are 2 or more icon faces for our daily typing job. (for English, Chinese, another one for Chinese...)

If the menu bar is always visible, I can see the status of this icon. However, most of the time mac will hide it in seconds when my pointer(arrow shape) leaves the top edge.

Blindly starting to type, I usually have to delete a couple of times and type again w/ the right input mode.

――――――――――――――――

My plan is to find the way to detect the status of the status icon, so that I can print such information on the status bar of my editor MacVim and always know what's the current input mode.

Every time we touch the CapsLock key, the input mode toggles with the icon image changing between [A] and [[image: OpenVanilla]] for English and Chinese, respectively.

I have no clue about where I can get status icon's status in Mac system. Please help.